# How can I completely copy a Clojure symbol to a new symbol?

Tags: performance, matrix, clojure, immutability, mutable

I have code which directly mutates a matrix for performance. Before I mutate it I want to get a complete copy to store in a new symbol, which is then used by the mutation process. Is there anyway that I can copy a Clojure symbol's contents into a new symbol so that the first can be mutated without affecting the second?

Here is one of my failed attempts:

```
(var mat1 (clatrix/matrix (clatrix/ones 2 2)))
(var mat1)
(intern 'analyzer.core 'mat1 (clatrix/matrix (clatrix/ones 2 2)))
mat1
(intern 'analyzer.core 'mat2 mat1)
mat2
(clatrix/set mat1 0 0 2)
mat1
mat2
```

And of course, this does not work:

```
(def mat1 (clatrix/matrix (clatrix/ones 2 2)
(def mat2 mat1)
```

I also attempted (but not sure if I'm doing it right here anyway):

```
(def mat1 (clatrix/matrix (clatrix/ones 2 2)
(def mat2 `mat1)
```

and

```
(def mat1 (clatrix/matrix (clatrix/ones 2 2))
(def mat2 ~mat1)
```

and

```
(def mat1 (clatrix/matrix (clatrix/ones 2 2))
(def mat2 (.dup mat1))
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have benchmarked the answers presented so far. I'm not sure what the symbol of the lines means.
Setup:

```
(def mat1 (clatrix/ones 1000 1000) ; Creates a 1000x1000 matrix of 1.0 in each element.
```

From @Mars:

```
(criterium.core/bench (let [mat2 (clatrix/matrix mat1)]))
```

[image: benchmark1]

From @JoG:

```
(criterium.core/bench (let [mat2 (read-string (pr-str mat1))]))
```

[image: benchmark2]

**For more general cases**

@JoG's solution will work for data structures that serialize into strings well. If someone has ideas about how to make a more general solution, please respond, and I will update this.

Comment: Does the library support transients?  That is the way it is usually done in clojure.

Comment: @stonemetal I am not sure if it does. It implements ISeq, so it might. It would be great if you could supply an answer using transients.

Comment: I believe the funny character is supposed to be the Greek letter mu.  Criterium prints mu followed by "s" for microseconds.  You can see that in the first listing, the standard deviation is in funny-char + "s" units, which would make sense if funny-char was mu, since the standard deviation should be a lot smaller than the mean.  When I run the benchmark the second test displays a mean in mu-s units.  (But as you noted in the comment on JoG's answer, the `read-string` method doesn't produce the right result: `(= 'A (read-string (pr-str mat1))) ; ==> true`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `matrix` again:

```
(require '[clatrix.core :as clatrix])
; nil

(def mat1 (clatrix/matrix [[1 1][1 1]]))
; #'user/mat1

(def mat2 (clatrix/matrix mat1))
; #'user/mat2

mat1
;  A 2x2 matrix
;  -------------
;  1.00e+00  1.00e+00 
;  1.00e+00  1.00e+00 

(clatrix/set mat1 0 0 2)
; #<DoubleMatrix [2.000000, 1.000000; 1.000000, 1.000000]>

mat1
;  A 2x2 matrix
;  -------------
;  2.00e+00  1.00e+00 
;  1.00e+00  1.00e+00 

mat2
;  A 2x2 matrix
;  -------------
;  1.00e+00  1.00e+00 
;  1.00e+00  1.00e+00
```

Answer (score -2):

Given the matrix itself is also a clojure datastrucure how about

```
(def copy (read-string (pr-str original)))
```

pr-str dumps the data structure as a string, read-string evaluates it back.

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not seem to work. The type of the result is `Symbol`, not `clatrix.core.Matrix`.

Comment: Even if it works, it's not idiomatic to serialize/deserialize strings just to copy data.